# does firefox and opera support zIndex style attribute via javascript

Tags: css, dom, xhtml, z-index

javascript snippet:

```
var ele = document.getElementById( "somelement" );
ele.style.zIndex = 15;
```

Basically i want to know does firefox and opera support .style.zIndex attribue? b/c i test the above in my code and the zIndex does not seem to reflect..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://fiddle.jshell.net/KdAYc/1/

Also, as other's might suggest, the element that is being given a specified `z-index` will need to be positioned with either `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`. Default is usually `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox certainly does - not sure about Opera.  It may be that some other CSS property is conflicting with the element on which you're setting `.style.zIndex` - for example, I have seen problems occur when trying to place an element 'on top of' another element that has `position: relative`.  Do you have example code that you can post?

Comment: actually all sibling elements of the element are in absolute mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that the elements that you have a z-index for don't have the following css attribute:

```
position:absolute;
```

If the positioning is not absolute, it won't work.

Comment: nope, they all have position absolute, except the parent, it has relative.